# Usage of 'DIRS' attributes of TEMPLATES and static files in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to Django and back-end development in a general. I am currently trying to build a very simple app. I saw some tutorials and am a little bit confused about 2 things:

**1.** What is the use of the attributes `DIRS` below in the picture? I knew that it was somehow used for "registering" templates but in my own apps, I didn't register it and somehow it still worked normally.

Here is the code of the DIRS attribute in TEMPLATES in my settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [], 
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    }, ]
```

This is the structure of my project:

[image: Project_structure]

(Sorry for the inconvenience of not having an image directly because I don't have enough reputation)

**2.** What does it mean to "deploy" static files and why is it a better way than let Django automatically "deploy" the files by itself? Here is the link to the documentation where they said on why we needed to serve/ deploy static files (in "Serving the files" note): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

I really appreciate any thorough explanation on how things work since I am a beginner. I would be grateful if you guys provide any resources for Django practice as well!

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not as screenshot.

Comment: Just fixed it, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. DIRS and static files deployment are absolutely unrelated things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DIRS` is an optional set of paths where Django should look for templates to render in the first place. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#dirs)

`APP_DIRS` if enabled then Django will look for templates to render in every app's `templates` subfolder. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#app-dirs)

[Example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-the-project-s-templates-directory) of overriding templates from `blog` app `blog/templates/blog/...` folder with templates stored in additional `<BASE_DIR>/additional_templates` folder.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    "blog",
    ...,
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "additional_templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        # ...
    },
]
```

If you call `render(request, 'blog/profile.html')` Django will try to find this template in `<BASE_DIR>/additional_templates/blog/profile.html` location at first, if there is no such file, it will go to blog app folder and will try to find `blog/templates/blog/profile.html`

If you don't have templates located somewhere else `<app_name>/templates` then you don't need to define `DIRS` parameter. That's why template rendering works in your project. Your templates are in **jobs** app folder: `jobs/templates/index.html`, `APP_DIRS` is enabled, nothing additional is required.