# Internal server error on cmd,TemplateDoesNotExist at / index.html

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm working on building a web app using Django and encountering the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\New folder\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
   response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\New folder\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in      _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\New folder\core\home\views.py", line 10, in home
    return HttpResponse(render(request, 'index.html'))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\New folder\env\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\New folder\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\New folder\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html'
```

D:\New folder\core\home\template\index.html

basic html code

D:\New folder\core\setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

EXTERNAL_APPS = [
    'home',
]

INSTALLED_APPS += EXTERNAL_APPS
```

D:\New folder\core\views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html'))

def success_page(request):
    print("* "*10)
    return HttpResponse("""<h1>Page has Been created successfully</h1>
                        </br>
                        <hr>
                        <p1> Hello world</p1>""")
```

D:\New folder\core\urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home.views impor

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home, name="home"),
    path('Success-page',success_page,name ="success_page")
]
```

tried many approaches from stack overflow still same error. help me fixing this error

Comment: There was a quesion asked recently about template location resolution options, please take a look at the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77910310/usage-of-dirs-attributes-of-templates-and-static-files-in-django/77914477#77914477

Comment: And it seems you're not using default Django project structure. Consider recreating folder structur by calling `startproject` and `startapp` commands [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: core is the project and home is app and created template in home file

Answer (score 0):

hope you are well buddy. I think this is a simple problem and hopefully we can work through it.

change the directory template to templates.

```
Add to settings.py:
```

TEMPLATES = [
{
...
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],  # Add this line
...
'APP_DIRS': True,
...
},
]

Remove the extra bracket:
return render(request, 'index.html')

If home is your app I would add a urls.py file in the app and add a url in there keeping things more organised. In the root urls point the url towards the app urls.

```
ROOT URLS:
from django.urls import path, include
path('home/', include('home.urls')),
```

then inside home app add the url.py:

```
APP URLS:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

path('', views.home, name='home'),
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i have tried but still the same error

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your folder structure please and post it ?

Answer (score 0):

ok so lets add the following to your project:
Views.py:

```
def index(request):
return render(request, 'index.html')
```

urls.py (in app):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

path('index/', views.index, name='index'),
```

In your app create a templates folder. In the templates folder create an index.html file. Fill it with the standard html template and create a

## HelloWorld

Your root url.py should point towards your app.

Run that and lets see what happens.